# Refresh Skrollr after resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, skrollr

I want the `<nav>` to become fixed after the user passes the first "block" (`height: 100%;`). I decided to use Skrollr because it is the only way I know to make the "change" immediately, without bugs on mobile and in IE. So I did this:

```
$("nav").attr("data-" + $("header").height(), "position: fixed;");
```

This is works great (the `<nav>` is right after the `<header>`), until you resizes the page. So I did this:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var style = $("nav").attr("style");
    $('nav').each(function() {
        var attributes = this.attributes;
        var i = attributes.length;
        while( i-- ){
            this.removeAttributeNode(attributes[i]);
        }
    })
    $("nav").attr("data-" + $("header").height(), "position: fixed;");
    $("nav").attr({"data-0": "position: absolute;", "style": style});
});
```

It takes the new height, and add it as a attr and deletes all others attr (because if not it will add you a lot: data-500, data-501, data-502, data-503...) and by looking at the code - it works great. The problem is that the Skrollr doesn't "sees" the change. what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Thats was easy. One line instead of 20 lines.

```
var s = skrollr.init({
    constants: {
        menuresize: function() {
            return $("header").height();
        },
        vh: '100p'
    }
});
```

and to the nav I add `data-_menuresize="position: fixed;"` (and it explaines what `menuresize`
means in the code above).

Enjoy `:D`!